# I can't split the viewport

Tags: 3d-view

So, as is clearly visible, I don't have ay splitting lines or such. I tried CTRL+UP and SHIFT+SPACE but that didn't work. Please help, because this project is nearly impossible without multiple views.
[image]

Comment: Well that looks exactly like a shift+space thing to me, but u said u tried that already ...

Comment: What if you click "Back to previous" in the view drop down at the top of your screen shot? Just tried CTRL+UP and get the same message, clicking it gets the view back.